# Move E-mails into specific folder using keyboard shortcut in Outlook 2010

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2010, autohotkey

I am looking for a way to move e-mails in Outlook to a specific folder.

For example:

> <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> - Will automatically move highlighted messages into "FOLDERA" without any popups or anything.

I know I would be able to figure this out with Auto Hot Key.

Does anyone have a way to do this in Outlook with macros or something? Or a clean way of doing it with AHK?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Outlook 2010 you can use Quick Steps to do this.

On the Home tab, click `Create New` in the Quick Step window.

[image]

Then name your step, choose `Move to folder` action, then choose the folder to move it to. At the bottom of the window you can assign a shortcut key.

[image]

Choose Finish. Your new step is now available in the Quick Steps window or using the shortcut key.

Comment: is there a way to use a shortcut key that is simpler other than ctrl+shift ? I would like to use a single key to move to another folder

Comment: You can use PowerToys and its Keyboard Manager to remap shorcuts, mapping a simpler shortcut to CTRL-SHIFT-1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/keyboard-manager#remap-shortcuts

Answer (score 3):

To move an item in **Outlook-2010**; you should use:

> CTRL+SHIFT+V

For an comprehensive reference of *shortcut-keys* in **Outlook-2010** take a look at following link:

https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-for-Outlook-3cdeb221-7ae5-4c1d-8c1d-9e63216c1efd

Comment: This does not answer the question. Please reread it carefully...they do not want "*any popups or anything*". Using your method opens a dialog window requiring input.

Comment: Yeah, this is not what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: In any case, this tip was usefull for me, and it is still valid for outlook 2016.

Answer (score 3):

One way to achieve this is via Outlook "Quick Steps":

1. In the 'Home' tab of the Ribbon of the main Outlook window, click the 'Manage Quick Steps' button in the 'Quick Steps' group:

[image: Outlook snip]

2. Add a new 'Move to Folder' quick step. Choose a useful name; check the box for 'move to folder' and select the desired destination folder; and optionally check 'mark as read' if you always want messages marked as read when moved.
3. Click 'Options'.  In the 'Edit Quick Step' dialog that appears, in the 'Shortcut key' drop-down at the bottom choose one of the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[number]</kbd> key combinations to associate with the Quick Step.
4. Click 'Save' and 'OK'.

Now, pressing the shortcut key you selected should move both (i) selected message(s) in a mailbox folder view and (ii) a currently open message to the selected folder.

Answer (score 0):

In Outlook from Office 365 suite, here goes an AHK snippet that implements the "keyboard shortcut" from the [documentation page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/keyboard-shortcuts-for-outlook-3cdeb221-7ae5-4c1d-8c1d-9e63216c1efd?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

- From the documentation, to "Move an item to a folder.", on needs to press "Alt+H, M, V, and select a folder from the list".

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe OUTLOOK.EXE
    ^m:: 
        send !h
        send m
        send v
        send o  ; This is to further trigger the "Move items" dialog
    return
#IfWinActive
; snippet in AHK 1.x
```