# How do I expand all folders in the Outlook "Go to Folder..." dialog?

Tags: windows-7, email, microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2010

Whenever I restart Outlook (2010) and I press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> shortcut, the folder tree starts in a completely collapsed view. This isn't really helpful, as I use the keyboard to navigate to the subfolders, thus I need them all expanded in order to find them.

[image]

I already [found a Macro](http://vboffice.net/en/developers/expand-all-folders/?mnu=2&cmd=showitem) that expands all folders in the folder pane (to the left) on startup. This works well, but it does not apply to the *Go to Folder* dialog. I also know that I can move messages to specific folders [with *Quick Steps*](https://superuser.com/questions/861377/move-e-mails-into-specific-folder-using-keyboard-shortcut-in-outlook-2010).

But how do I expand the "Inbox" tree in the above dialog, automatically?

Comment: What about an AutoHotKey script? Something like `CTRL+Y...I..N..B..O..X...Right Arrow`? Though that will only expand Inbox, not any of its subfolders

Answer (score 1):

You can press <kbd>*</kbd> on your numpad to do a recursive expansion of the selected folder in the tree.

I haven't yet worked out how to do this if you don't have a numpad.

(<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> doesn't seem to work.)

Comment: @slhck, @Daniel - This works +1 each. Moreover, my keyboard also doesn't have a dedicated NumPad but the NumPad keys are embedded onto the existing TYPEWRITER keys. In my case, the `*` key of NumPad is embedded on to the key `P`. Now, all you have to do is to open the `Go-To Folder` dialog > Select the root folder (e.g. Inbox) > Turn on the `Num Lock` > Press the embedded `*` key (in my case the letter key `P`. NOTE: Press this key WITHOUT pressing `SHIFT`). I got all the subfolders under Inbox expanded! Good luck!! :)

Answer (score -1):

Actually, this "Go to Folder..." dialog remembers all expanded folders for current Outlook session. So, you can expand all required folders once after starting Outlook and then you'll find all your folders expanded until you restart Outlook.

Comment: Thanks, I know this. But as I said at the beginning of my question, I am specifically talking about the situation after restarting Outlook. I have to restart it quite often, so expanding it once and then never closing Outlook is not an option for me.

Comment: No way to retain folder state across sessions in this dialog, sorry.

Comment: I'm not actually sure if this is the only solution. If there was a way to have a macro to expand this dialog or some other script that does it with one click, that'd also work.

Comment: No. No VBA access to this dialog.